# Delete/move original email when replied to

Tags: vba, outlook

We have a ticket system that sends us tickets with the title "New Ticket Created: T20120803.0078" where the number is generated.

We reply to all saying we are working on the ticket. The reply title looks like this "RE: New Ticket Created: T20120803.0078".

My Outlook is set up to forward all tickets into one folder called "Tickets".

I am trying to figure out how when the email is replied to, it sends both the reply and the original to another folder called "InProgress".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`don't have a lot of time to figure this one out.`

Typically, at this sight we don't build code for people, but help them build the tweak or perfect code where they are struggling.

That said, I was intrigued by your question and wanted to learn myself, so I put something together for you. This should get you a great start, if it's not already exactly what you need.

**UPDATE:**

You don't even need VBA for the first part. You can set up a rule to move all sent messages with `"RE: New Ticket Created"` in the subject line to the `In Progress` folder. Therefore, you don't even need the whole first `IfF Then End If` block in the code below. (I've left it for reference, purposes).

**CODE**

All assumptions based on the settings you provided.

Place the code in the Application_ItemSend event of ThisOutlookSession object in Outlook VBE.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("myMailbox@myCompany.com").Folders("In Progress")


If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then 'if it's a mail item being sent

    Dim olMailCopy As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMailCopy = Item.Copy 'copy the item so we can move it and still have it send

    If InStr(1, olMailCopy.Subject, "New Ticket Created") > 0 Then '

        olMailCopy.Move olDestFolder ' move copy of mail to folder

        Dim strTicket As String
        strTicket = Mid(olMailCopy.Subject, InStrRev(olMailCopy.Subject, ": ") + 2) 'just grab ticket id

    End If

End If


Dim olLookUpFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set olLookUpFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("myMailbox@myCompany.com").Folders("Tickets")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

For Each olMail In olLookUpFolder.Items 'loop through Tickets folder to find original mail

    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, strTicket) > 0 Then 'look for unique ticket Id

        olMail.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder

        Exit For

    End If

Next

End Sub
```